# Importing Global instance of a Class in Python

Tags: python, class, import

In Python, I'm trying to create a few global objects that are available anywhere in a program if a module has been imported (similar to the logging module).

For example:

module: databaseinterface.py

import sqlite3

DATABASE = None

class Database:

> def **init**(self, location): ...

> def ViewQuery(self, query, params): ...

> def ModifyQuery(self, query, params): ...

def create_database(location):

> if not DATABASE:
>
> > DATABASE = Database(location)

module: main.py

import databaseinterface

databaseinterface.create_database("test.sqlite")
results = databaseinterface.DATABASE.ViewQuery("SELECT * from users")

But I get the error "ViewQuery" does not exist. Is there a neat way to have global instances available from an import?

cheers,
Brad

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a singleton class structure. It is a common code Design Pattern.

There are a lot of resources. e.g. [This Blog post](https://stackabuse.com/the-singleton-design-pattern-in-python/) Or just use: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+singleton

example code piece:

```
class SingletonGovt:
   __instance__ = None

   def __init__(self):
       """ Constructor.
       """
       if SingletonGovt.__instance__ is None:
           SingletonGovt.__instance__ = self
       else:
           raise Exception("You cannot create another SingletonGovt class")

   @staticmethod
   def get_instance():
       """ Static method to fetch the current instance.
       """
       if not SingletonGovt.__instance__:
           SingletonGovt()
       return SingletonGovt.__instance__
```